# Kubectl commands to EKS, from EC2 in a private networks, are timing out

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, kubectl, amazon-eks

This EKS cluster has a private endpoint only. My end goal is to deploy Helm charts on the EKS. I connect to an EC2 machine via SSM and I have already installed Helm and Kubectl on that machine. The trouble is that in a private network, the AWS APIs can't be called. So, instead of calling **aws eks update-kubeconfig --region region-code --name cluster-name** I have created the kubeconfig such as below.

```
apiVersion: v1
clusters:
- cluster:
    server: 1111111111111111.gr7.eu-west-1.eks.amazonaws.com
    certificate-authority-data: JTiBDRVJU111111111
  name: kubernetes
contexts:
- context:
    cluster: kubernetes
    user: aws
  name: aws
current-context: aws
kind: Config
preferences: {}
users:
- name: aws
  user:
    exec:
      apiVersion: client.authentication.k8s.io/v1alpha1
      command: aws
      args:
        - "eks"
        - "get-token"
        - "--cluster-name"
        - "this-is-my-cluster"
        # - "--role-arn"
        # - "role-arn"
      # env:
        # - name: AWS_PROFILE
        #   value: "aws-profile"
```

Getting the following error:

```
I0127 21:24:26.336266    3849 loader.go:372] Config loaded from file:  /tmp/.kube/config-eks-demo
I0127 21:24:26.337081    3849 round_trippers.go:435] curl -k -v -XGET  -H "Accept: application/json, */*" -H "User-Agent: kubectl/v1.21.2 (linux/amd64) kubernetes/d2965f0" 'http://1111111111111111.gr7.eu-west-1.eks.amazonaws.com/api?timeout=32s'
I0127 21:24:56.338147    3849 round_trippers.go:454] GET http://1111111111111111.gr7.eu-west-1.eks.amazonaws.com/api?timeout=32s  in 30001 milliseconds
I0127 21:24:56.338171    3849 round_trippers.go:460] Response Headers:
I0127 21:24:56.338238    3849 cached_discovery.go:121] skipped caching discovery info due to Get "http://1111111111111111.gr7.eu-west-1.eks.amazonaws.com/api?timeout=32s": dial tcp 10.1.1.193:80: i/o timeout
```

There is connectivity in the VPC, there are no issues with NACLs, security groups, port 80.

Comment: You have a private eks cluster and an ec2 in private network. If you do a **curl -v** to cluster endpoint, it returns connected or not? How can you know that your network is working? Did you set up vpc endpoints? How about IAM role ( instance profile) ? Did you edit aws-auth?

Comment: @FranxiHidro as in the errors logs above curl can't connect to the private IP. However, when running the "AWS Reachability Analysis" it shows that the instance can talk to that particular ENI. I've set up vpc endpoints for the EC2 instance (SSM) and EKS (sts, ecr, s3, autoscaling, ec2). I did not edit aws-auth as I need kubectl for that. I have configured AWS user credentials on the EC2 machine and configured kubeconfig with those credentials. These are the same user credentials that were used to deploy the cluster.

Comment: For vpc endpoints, you need s3 - endpoint type is gateway (need a route table here) and the rest (ec2, ecr_api, ecr_dkr, cwlogs, sts, autoscaling ...) are interface. For testing purpose, pls use open-all rule in security group. I don't remember it exactly but if you don't limit IPs connect to cluster api endpoint and your access key has enough permission, you can run **aws eks update-kubeconfig** command.

Comment: Btw, I don't really like the logs output, I just need **curl -v https://1111111111111111.gr7.eu-west-1.eks.amazonaws.com**, I think it will use **https** not http.

Comment: It's still using port 80 and is timing out. I can't run aws eks update-kubeconfig since that requires access to the AWS EKS APIs and there is no vpc endpoint for EKS just yet. I still don't understand why the connection problem when hitting the ENI in the same subnet. I've opened the security group to all traffic for testing.

Comment: You need to improve your knowledge, please read this docs https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/private-clusters.html

Answer (score 1):

That looks like this open EKS issue:  https://github.com/aws/containers-roadmap/issues/298

If that’s the case, upvote it so that the product team can prioritize it.  If you have Enterprise support your TAM can help there as well.

Comment: The EKS VPC endpoint is needed but I am sure there are workarounds. Otherwise, nobody could deploy an EKS cluster in a segregated environment.